# Formatting the datatip numbers from a Flex Barchart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I simply don't know how to do this. This is the code I have.

```
public function doFormatMoneda(valor:Number):String{
                var formatoMoneda:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter();
                formatoMoneda.precision = "2";
                formatoMoneda.rounding = "none"; 
                formatoMoneda.decimalSeparatorTo = "."; 
                formatoMoneda.thousandsSeparatorTo = ","; 
                formatoMoneda.useThousandsSeparator = "true"; 
                formatoMoneda.useNegativeSign = "true";
                formatoMoneda.currencySymbol = "$";
                formatoMoneda.alignSymbol = "left";

                return formatoMoneda.format(valor.toString());
            }

private function formatCurrency(hitData:HitData):String{
            var format:String = doFormatMoneda(Number(hitData));
            return format;          
        }


<mx:BarChart top="30" left="10" width="100%" dataProvider="{orgData}" dataTipFunction="formatCurrency" showDataTips="true" height="430" fontWeight="bold" id="bcCfds">
                    <mx:verticalAxis>
                        <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="mes"/>
                    </mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:series>
                    <mx:BarSeries 
                        yField="mes" 
                        xField="totalCancelada" 
                        labelField="totalCanceladaFormato"
                        displayName="Canceladas"
                        barWidthRatio="1.0"/>
                    <mx:BarSeries 
                        yField="mes" 
                        xField="totalPagada" 
                        labelField="totalPagadaFormato"
                        displayName="Pagadas"
                        barWidthRatio="1.0"/>
                    <mx:BarSeries 
                        yField="mes" 
                        xField="totalTerminada" 
                        labelField="totalTerminadaFormato"
                        displayName="Terminadas"
                        barWidthRatio="1.0"/>
                </mx:series>
            </mx:BarChart>  
            <mx:Legend dataProvider="{bcCfds}" direction="horizontal" />
```

It displays empty datatips. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: Is this Java? The syntax does not look like it.

Comment: Definitely not java, Flex perhaps?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was in a hurry, this is flex.

Comment: Check error property of your `CurrencyFormater` object after calling `format()` function. It should contain description of the error if anything went wrong during formatting (default behavior of formatter on error occurrence is returning empty String so it fits nicely in what you described)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get value of currency from hitdata and convert that to number.
you should try
Number(hitData.item) or some property of item which has CurrencyValue.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. Your comment below helped me completely to solve this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.formatters.CurrencyFormatter;
        import mx.charts.HitData;
        public function doFormatMoneda(valor:Number):String{ 
                var formatoMoneda:CurrencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter();  
                formatoMoneda.precision = "2";  
                formatoMoneda.rounding = "none"; 
                formatoMoneda.decimalSeparatorTo = ".";
                formatoMoneda.thousandsSeparatorTo = ",";  
                formatoMoneda.useThousandsSeparator = "true"; 
                formatoMoneda.useNegativeSign = "true"; 
                formatoMoneda.currencySymbol = "$";
                formatoMoneda.alignSymbol = "left";
                return formatoMoneda.format(valor.toString()); 
                }
private function formatCurrency(hitData:HitData):String{
          var format:String = doFormatMoneda(Number(hitData.item.totalCancelada));
          return format;                   
          }   
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

As arpit said,hitData.item is your handle on the object .you have to specify which property of this object you want to format.For example, i used totalCancelada and it works fine.

Comment: That works for a single dataprovider item, but the datatip ends up displaying the same value on each bar, which doesn't make any sense. What can I do to make it return the corresponding values for each bar chart element?

Comment: try  BarSeriesItem(hd.chartItem).xValue or similar property

Comment: Are you talking about overloading my current fucntion or using a different one like labelFunction?

Comment: No. Change current formatCurrency function. ChartItem will give u series specific datapoint and it's xValue or yvalue would be property will have currency info